# How to deserialize a JSON response to an object list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I've written a web API to access some JSON data on a file system. The API is set up to return the data as json to the client. However, when I try to deserialize the JSON response into a list of my objects, it fails.

I've tried cleaning up the response, as it seems to have extra characters in it, but that didn't seem to work as the cleaning tended to produce wonky non-JSON. I feel like I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be.

My data model class:

```
public abstract class CatalogueBase
{
    string name;
    string description;
    int id;

    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public string Description { get => description; set => description = value; }
    public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
}

public class Media : CatalogueBase
{
    MediaType type;
    MediaRating rating;
    string genre;

    public MediaType Type { get => type; set => type = value; }
    public MediaRating Rating { get => rating; set => rating = value; }
    public string Genre { get => genre; set => genre = value; }

    public Media()
    {

    }
}
```

The web API endpoint which is grabbing and sending over the data:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetMedia/")]
public ActionResult<string> GetAll()    
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(this.config.Value.JSONFileDirectory);
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> jsonFiles = new List<string>();
            string json;

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    jsonFiles.Add(Regex.Unescape(json));
                }  
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonFiles, Formatting.Indented);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not parse JSON file.", e);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound("No files were found in the catalog.");
    }
}
```

Note that each file contains a single `Media` object previously serialized as JSON.

The client side code which is calling the above endpoint:

```
public async Task<List<Media>> GetAllMedia()
{
    client = GetHttpClient(@"GetMedia/");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var media = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Media>>(content);
    return media;
}
```

And finally a sample JSONresponse I'm getting in my client:

```
"\"[\\r\\n  \\\"{\\\\\\\"Type\\\\\\\":0,\\\\\\\"Rating\\\\\\\":5,\\\\\\\"Genre\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Drama\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"Name\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Memes\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"Description\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"A movie set during the American Civil War\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"Id\\\\\\\":1}\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"{\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Id\\\\\\\": 2,\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Name\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Gods and Generals\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Description\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"A movie set during the American Civil War\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Type\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Movie\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Rating\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Excellent\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Genre\\\\\\\" : \\\\\\\"Drama\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\\n}\\\\r\\\\n\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"{\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Id\\\\\\\": 3,\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Name\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Avengers Endgame\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Description\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"The end of the Avengers series.\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Type\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Movie\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Rating\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Excellent\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n\\\\\\\"Genre\\\\\\\" : \\\\\\\"Action\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\\n}\\\\r\\\\n\\\"\\r\\n]\""
```

The JSON response itself looks like an issue to me, Way too many `\\` and other special characters. I've tried to clean it up with string .Replace calls, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

The actual error message:

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Error converting value ...json string.....  to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CatalogManager.Models.MediaManager.Media]'. Path '', line 1, position 732.)'

---

Edit: Tried some of the suggestions in the comments, and I received the following json response:

```
"[\"{\\\"Type\\\":0,\\\"Rating\\\":5,\\\"Genre\\\":\\\"Drama\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Memes\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"A movie set during the American Civil War\\\",\\\"Id\\\":1}\",\"{\\r\\n\\\"Id\\\": 2,\\r\\n\\\"Name\\\": \\\"Gods and Generals\\\",\\r\\n\\\"Description\\\": \\\"A movie set during the American Civil War\\\",\\r\\n\\\"Type\\\": \\\"Movie\\\",\\r\\n\\\"Rating\\\": \\\"Excellent\\\",\\r\\n\\\"Genre\\\" : \\\"Drama\\\"\\r\\n}\\r\\n\",\"{\\r\\n\\\"Id\\\": 3,\\r\\n\\\"Name\\\": \\\"Avengers Endgame\\\"\\r\\n\\\"Description\\\": \\\"The end of the Avengers series.\\\",\\r\\n\\\"Type\\\": \\\"Movie\\\",\\r\\n\\\"Rating\\\": \\\"Excellent\\\",\\r\\n\\\"Genre\\\" : \\\"Action\\\"\\r\\n}\\r\\n\"]"
```

And when I try to parse it with JObject, I get the following error:

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at CatalogManager.Pages.IndexModel.OnGet() in C:\Users\tpzap_000\source\repos\CatalogManager\Pages\Manager\Index.cshtml.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory.ActionResultHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.<InvokeHandlerMethodAsync>d__30.MoveNext()

Inner Exception 1:
JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

---

Final Edit: I tried dbc's suggestion and that worked. I think the core problem was on my API side I was parsing my json files as strings rather than into my Media model object and then using Newtonsoft to parse it into properly formed json. I changed my API side code to the following:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetMedia/")]
public ActionResult<List<Media>> GetAll()    
{

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(this.config.Value.JSONFileDirectory);
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Media> jsonFiles = new List<Media>();
            string json;

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Media currentMedia = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Media>(json);

                    //jsonFiles.Add(Regex.Unescape(json));
                    jsonFiles.Add(currentMedia);
                }  
            }



            return Ok(jsonFiles);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not parse JSON file.", e);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound("No files were found in the catalog.");
    }

}
```

And it worked successfully on the front end.

Comment: asp.net will convert your result to JSON. Just return jsonFiles (and of course change the return type)

Comment: In you GetAllMedia, method try doing a adding this line and hit me back with the result you get in the debug console. `var jobject = JObject.Parse(content); Console.WriteLine(jobject)`. And also change `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonFiles, Formatting.Indented);` to `return Ok(jsonFiles)`

Comment: Tried what you suggested, but the JObject.Parse fails to parse it. Updated the post with the outcome.

@Sir Rufo, I did get rid of the Serialization in my return statement on the API side, and that seems to be a step in the right direction. The json is a bit cleaner I think.

Comment: 1) Your method has the signature `ActionResult<string>` but what content type do you actually want to return?  `text/plain` or `application/json`?  2) What should the response contain, exactly?  3) Why are you doing `Regex.Unescape(json)`?

Comment: 1) I'd prefer to return application/json. 2) Just the json data I'm pulling from the files, that's it. 3) I was doing that to try and clean up the json string I'm pulling from the files. It seemed like it hada bunch of special characters in it(\r, \n, \\, etc.). I've since removed that once I added Sir Rufo's suggestion.

Comment: OK, does each file contain a single serialized `Media` object,  or something different?  If so, why not just deserialize each one and return a `List<Media>` explicitly?  Is it purely for performance reasons that you don't want to parse and re-serialize the files on the server?

Comment: Each file on the system contains 1 Media object represented as json. For example:
{"Type":0,"Rating":5,"Genre":"Drama","Name":"Gettysburg","Description":"A movie set during the American Civil War","Id":1}
At the moment, I'm not worried about optimizing anything. I'm working on learning Web API so I'm just trying to get it to work right now. I could try changing the API return a List<Media> objects instead of the json string I have been.

Comment: Then start with that.  If the client and server types match you should be good to go.

Comment: That worked. It seems I was causing the problem by parsing the json as a string and returning that instead of parsing it directly to my model object and then using Newtonsoft to convert that to JSON. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should I make it an answer then?  It's better not to have the answer in the question itself.

Comment: Yeah it would be easier I think for anyone else having this problem if they could just look at an answer instead of a long comment chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that your server is returning a `string`, but the client expects `application/json` content containing a serialized `List<Media>`, thereby causing a compatibility problem during deserialization.

The easiest way to ensure that the client and server are compatible is to return *exactly the same type* from the server, i.e. `List<Media>` (or [`ActionResult<List<Media>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#actionresultt-type) if you want the possibility of returning an error).  This allows the framework to handle both the serialization and content negotiation, so you don't have to.  The following does the job:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetMedia/")]
public ActionResult<List<Media>> GetAll()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(this.config.Value.JSONFileDirectory);
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
            return files.Select(f =>
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(f))
                    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
                    {
                        return serializer.Deserialize<Media>(jsonReader);
                    }
                })
                .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not parse JSON file.", e);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound("No files were found in the catalog.");
    }
}
```

Notes:

- It can be more efficient to deserialize a JSON file via direct streaming rather than loading into an intermediate `string`, then deserializing the string.  See [Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage) for details.  If this is not a concern you could just do:

  ```
  return files.Select(f => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Media>(File.ReadAllText(f))).ToList();
  ```